# When using dotCover in a TeamCity build configuration, is there an environment variable for code coverage percentage?

Tags: teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

When using [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) to manage .net projects, we like to use [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) to evaluate our code coverage.  In the past using [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/), there was a way to retrieve the code coverage percentage using an environment variable.

We liked this and we would set the Project description to use this variable so that from the dashboard (overview) you could easily see the code coverage.  I believe NCover had some output variable that TeamCity made available.  I don't recall exactly what it was, but I believe it was something like:

```
%env.ncover.coverage%
```

Does anybody know how to do this using **dotCover** with TeamCity?  I realize it may actually be 3 values; 1 for Classes, 1 for Method, and 1 for Statements.

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity publishes coverage percentage as statistics values. Unfortunately, this is done after all build steps (build runner) are finished. You may write a server side plugin that will make the data available. Please describe why no you need it? Probably TeamCity REST plugin is able to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Eugene Petrenko.  As I mentioned in the second paragraph, it would just be nice (easy) to see the coverage from the Overview as opposed to clicking into the build a few pages.  Its a luxury that I thought we used to have but I don't recall how we got it working.  I've posted this on JetBrains website also and have not had any responses.